# What API should I use to get the property of a object in Nebula JS (QLIK Extension)

Tags: qliksense

I have a list of sheets generated by filtering  `getAllInfos` method.

Now I need to know whether each sheet is published or not what method should I use to find its property?

```
let sheetList = [];
const app = useApp();
(async () => {
sheetList= (await app.getAllInfos()).filter((x)=> x.qType === 'sheet');
 })();
```

`getAllInfos()` has only `qid` and `qtype`,
I need the property of Published: Boolean.

I searched the documentation but I don't know how to use some of the methods so I'm not sure which one to use:

[Qlik API Documentation](https://qlik.dev/apis/json-rpc/qix/doc#%23%2Fentries%2FDoc%2Fentries%2FGetAppProperties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getObject` method provided by the Qlik engine API. This method retrieves a generic object from the app and can be combined with the `getLayout` method to access specific properties.

In your case, to find out whether each sheet is published or not, you need to get each sheet by its `qId` using the `getObject` method, then use the `getLayout` method to access its properties:

```js
let sheetList = [];
const app = useApp();
(async () => {
  const allInfos = await app.getAllInfos();
  sheetList = allInfos.filter((info) => info.qType === 'sheet');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < sheetList.length; i++) {
    const sheet = await app.getObject(sheetList[i].qId);
    const layout = await sheet.getLayout();
    console.log(`Sheet: ${sheetList[i].qId}, Published: ${layout.qMeta.published}`);
  }
})();
```

- `app.getObject(sheetList[i].qId)` fetches the object (sheet) with the specified `qId`.
- `sheet.getLayout()` returns the layout of the sheet, which contains its properties.
- `layout.qMeta.published` accesses the 'published' property of the sheet.

This should log the `qId` and the 'published' status of each sheet in the console.